# How to send a message on connect from a Netty based server to every incomming client connection?

Tags: netty

Code snippet.

An attempt to write a hello to the connection made to server. I assume the channelActive is called once a connection is made and use the context to write the response. But nothing is received at the client.

```
public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
....
//edit checking status of future
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {


    super.channelActive(ctx);
//    ChannelFuture f = ctx.write("hello"); //EDIT2  : cant use String use ByteBuf
        ByteBuf msg = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("hello", CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    ctx.write(msg);
    if (f.isSuccess()) {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("failed");
        f.cause().printStackTrace(); // EDIT2: Helpful in determining cause of failure

    }
    if (f.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Done");
    }
    System.out.println("channelActive");
}    .....
}
```

Comment: What netty version are you using? Did you try to get the channel future produced by the write and seeing if it succeeded?

Comment: Using netty-4.0.0.CR9
Future failed and returned done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it like that. Channel operations are asynchronous, isSucess() is meaningless unless isDone() returns true. Read the documentation for [ChannelFuture](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html), and if the operation really fails, write out the `cause()` of the failure.

Comment: The cause() pointed me the right direction. You cant use string objects for writing. I had to use a  ByteBuf
    ByteBuf msg = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("hello", CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.
Code edited with EDIT2 comments and got the test to work.
Prior to fix isDone was true and isSuccess was false.